# gnupg: set subkey expiration date in the past

Tags: clock, gnupg

I would like to set the expiration date of a GPG subkey in the past, but `gpg --edit-key` does not allow me to. Is there any workaround to that?

Rationale: it is useful to set the expiration date of a subkey in the past in order to temporarily disable it. If you just revoke it, you lose the ability to enable it again later on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible workaround is to use `faketime` to convince `gnupg` to not complain. See [this other question](https://serverfault.com/q/138325/85606):

```
$ faketime 'last week' gpg2 --edit-key ABCDEF12
```

and then use ordinary commands to expire the subkey tomorrow. That "tomorrow" will actually be six days ago.

Comment: Thank you for showing me faketime...